# Set the combobox default value before binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

How to set the selected value of the Kendo combobox if upon initializing and before dataBound.
I tried to attach it in dataBound event but the model will set to undefined or null after dataBound. This is my code at dataBound

```
// set my defaul value here
$scope.$on("kendoRendered", function (event, widget) {
     $scope.Gender = 2;
});

dataBound: function () 
    {                  
        console.log($scope.Gender); // the $scope.Gender now is empty
        this.value(2); // this 2 here is female            
    }
```

There is also a fiddle for testing [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/bcfba1dg/9/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Which outcome do you want to change in your fiddle?

Comment: My outcome would be, if i set the value $scope.Gender anywhere on my code even if before dataBound or after dataBound, the combobox would respond or select the item automatically